# Flyway Command line unable to find migrations on filesystem

Tags: flyway

I am using flyway command line tool for DB migrations. If I put the SQL migrations in **SQL** directory it works fine. However if I set the Locations property to path on file system, it fails without any warning or error.

for eg: `flyway.locations=/file-path/`

How to specify the file system path? I don't want to put my migrations in **SQL** directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported yet: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/108

As a workaround you can symlink /sql to the directory you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Does flyway ant plugin supports multiple schemas with different location for migration for each one? I know flyway does in general, But ant plugin doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: Use one flyway:migrate call for each. See also:  http://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq.html#multiple-schemas

Comment: I tried to do that but the second flyway:migrate call seems to use the schema_version table of the previously migrated schema. How to make them use individual schema_version table?

Comment: Either the schemas or the table property has to be different.

Comment: Schemas are different. For eg: Consider a case with schema S1 and S2, first I migrate S1 and S1.schema_version table is updated but after that when I try to migrate S2 it checks S1.schema_version instead of S2.schema_version.

Answer (score 0):

You should prefix the absolute path to the 'migration' directory with the String "filesystem:", like this:

```
String path = "/my/project/sql/migrate/";
migrateRelease("filesystem:" + path);
flyway.setLocations(location);
flyway.migrate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Axel, it is working on version 3.2.1. The only remaining thing to pay attention is the version number on your migration files that should be more than the one on schema_version table. Otherwise, you might end up with the following result after running migrate command;

```
Flyway 3.2.1 by Boxfuse

Database: jdbc:mysql://...
Validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.009s)
Current version of schema `ref_db`: 1
Schema `ref_db` is up to date. No migration necessary.
```